# Solutions to $a_1+2a_2+\cdots+ka_k = 1979$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

> For $k = 1,2,\ldots$ consider the $k$-tuples $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k)$ of positive integers such that $$a_1+2a_2+\cdots+ka_k = 1979.$$ Show that there are as many such $k$-tuples with odd $k$ as there are with even $k$.

We know that we need only check up to $k = 62$ because otherwise it is just $0$. Since I don't see an easy way of counting solutions to $a_1+2a_2+3a_3 = 1979$ for example, is there something else we could do to prove the question?

Also it is interesting to note that $1979$ is a prime. Although the result doesn't seem easily generalizable if we replace $1979$ by some other integer.

I tried the following.

**Attempt:**

We first see that the number of solutions for some $k$ is given by the coefficient of $x^{1979}$ in the expansion of $$(x+x^2+\cdots)(x^2+x^4+\cdots)\cdots(x^{k}+x^{2k}+\cdots) = \prod_{i=1}^k\dfrac{x^i}{1-x^{i}}.$$ Thus, we need to show that $$Q(x) = \sum_{k=1; 2 \mid k}^{62}\left(\prod_{i=1}^k\dfrac{x^i}{1-x^{i}}\right)-\sum_{k = 1; 2 \nmid k}^{61}\left(\prod_{i=1}^k\dfrac{x^i}{1-x^{i}}\right)$$ doesn't contain the term $x^{1979}$ in its expansion.

Comment: One way to proceed would be to find a bijection between odd and even $k$-tuples.

Comment: @Semiclassical I agree, but how would I go about doing that?

Comment: I think you need to check up to $k=1979$, since (k_1,k_2,...,k_1979)=(0,0,...,1) gives 1979

Comment: @Aweygan Recall the question says positive.

Comment: @user19405892 You are correct.  My apologies.

Comment: It would be helpful to read [this](https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math172-spring10/partitions.pdf), and check if $1979$ is a number of the form $(3k^2 \pm k)/2$.

Comment: @i707107 That is for a partition, but how does that hold here? In particular, if we can show that there are as many such $k$-tuples with odd $k$ as there are with even $k$ and $a_i$ positive if and only if there are as many such $k$-tuples with odd $k$ as there are with even $k$ and $a_i$ nonnegative and less than or equal to one, we are done.

Comment: [This](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~dcranston/490/slides/pent_thm.pdf) will be better. It will help you understand the bijection visually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(a_1, \cdots , a_k)$ be a solution to the desired equation. Note that this describes a partition of $1979$ given as
$$\lambda = (a_1 \times 1, a_2\times 2, a_3\times 3, \cdots , a_k\times k),$$
i.e. each positive solution describes a unique partition of $1979$ with *largest part* $k$. Turning the Young diagram of the partition sideways, this translates to a partition with exactly $k$ parts. In fact, you can check that the stipulation that $a_i > 0$ translates to the fact that we get a partition with not only exactly $k$ parts but $k$ *distinct* parts.

Therefore we have a bijection with solutions $k$-tuples solutions and partitions with exactly $k$ distinct parts. Out problem is therefore reduced to proving that the number of partitions of $1979$ into an even number of distinct parts is exactly equal to the number of partitions of $1979$ into an odd number of distinct parts.

This was a problem tackled by Euler, whose solution is encapsulated in his pentagonal number theorem.

**Euler's Pentagonal Number Theorem:** Let $P_{DE}(n)$ and $P_{DO}(n)$ denote the number of partitions of $n$ with an even/odd number of distinct parts respectively. Then
$$P_{DE}(n) - P_{DO}(n) = \begin{cases}(-1)^k & n=\frac{3k^2-k}{2}\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

In particular, the number of distinct even and odd partitions are equal except when $n$ is a generalized pentagonal number.

The proof of this theorem is not very difficult and is available in many places online so I won't prove it here.

The result now follows by noting that $1979$ is *not* a generalized pentagonal number (which it is not).